# not connecting correctly to websockets from node/swiftui

Tags: node.js, swiftui, websocket

app description:
a job app where people can create jobs and other people apply to them
once a job application has been approved, it should create a chat so that users can communicate.

issue:
im having an issue joining a chat/room from the controller where the job application is approved.
the chat they joined works but the message apper more than once, super weird.

note:
if i exit the application and reopen it the chat works fine, super weird

video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJVU6IxsemU

i will pay if you can solve this.

below is the socket handler in node::

```
// socketHandler.js
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const { instrument } = require("@socket.io/admin-ui");
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const { get_chat_messages_query } = require('../constants/queries/chat_messages');
const { get_chat_query } = require('../constants/queries/chat')
const { get_users_query } = require('../constants/queries/user');

const ChatMessageService = require('../services/db/chat_messages');
const UserService = require('../services/db/user');
const ChatService = require('../services/db/chats');
const QueryUtil = require('../util/query_util');
// const ChatUtil = require('../util/chat_util');


const chat_message_service = new ChatMessageService();
const query_util = new QueryUtil();

const chat_service = new ChatService();
const user_service = new UserService()
// const chat_util = new ChatUtil()
const base_url = "chat_message-";

// Maintain a mapping between user IDs and socket IDs
const user_socket_map = new Map();

// Ensure that socket.user is set after successful authentication
const authenticateUser = (socket, token) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
            socket.user = decoded;
            user_socket_map.set(socket.user.user_id, socket.id);
            resolve();
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Authentication error:', err.message);
            socket.emit('authentication_error', { message: err.message });
            socket.disconnect(true);
            reject(err.message);
        }
    });
};


const join_chats = async (socket, user_id) => {
    console.log("join_chats()\n")

    const query_params = { "users": `IN$["${user_id}"]`, }

    const { query, values } = query_util.build_query(query_params);
    const complete_query = get_chat_query + query


    try {
        const result = await chat_service.get_chat(complete_query, values);
        const rooms = result.rows.map((chat) => chat.id);
        for (chat_id of rooms) {
            socket.join(chat_id);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("E: ", e)
    }

    console.log("result: ", result.rows)

}


class SocketManager {
    constructor(server) {
        this.io = new Server(server, {
            cors: {
                origin: process.env.ALLOWED_ORIGINS.split(','),
                methods: ["GET", "POST"],
            },
        });

        this.io.on('connection', (socket) => {
            console.log('A user connected ', socket.id);
            console.log("Number of sockets connected ", user_socket_map.size);

            // Check if the user ID is already connected
            if (socket.user && user_socket_map.has(socket.user.user_id)) {
                const existingSocketId = user_socket_map.get(socket.user.user_id);
                // Disconnect the existing socket
                this.io.to(existingSocketId).emit('disconnect', 'Another connection detected');
                this.io.sockets.sockets.get(existingSocketId).disconnect(true);
            }

            socket.on('authenticate', async (token) => {
                console.log("Someone is trying to auth")
                try {
                    await authenticateUser(socket, token);
                    await join_chats(socket, socket.user.user_id)
                    // Continue with other event listeners or logic after successful authentication
                } catch (error) {
                    // Handle authentication error if needed
                }
            });

            socket.on('disconnect', () => {
                // Remove the user ID from the mapping when the socket disconnects
                if (socket.user && user_socket_map.has(socket.user.user_id)) {
                    user_socket_map.delete(socket.user.user_id);
                    console.log("Number of sockets connected ", user_socket_map.size);
                }
            });

            socket.on(`${base_url}get`, async (data) => {
                console.log(`GET messages for chat: ${data.chat_id}`);

                try {
                    const { query, values } = query_util.build_query({ "chat_id": `${data.chat_id}` });
                    const result = await chat_message_service.get_chat_messages(get_chat_messages_query + query, values);
                    console.log("result rows: ", result.rows.length)

                    // Emit the messages back to the client using the same event name
                    socket.emit(`${base_url}get`, result.rows);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error("Error fetching chat messages:", error.message);
                    socket.emit(`${base_url}get_error`, { message: error.message });
                }
            });


            socket.on(`${base_url}create`, async (data) => {

                try {
                    // check if logged user is in chat
                    // create messages
                    const result = await chat_message_service.create_chat_messages({
                        message: data.message,
                        chat_id: data.chat_id,
                        user_id: socket.user.user_id
                    });



                    this.io.to(data.chat_id).emit(`${base_url}message_created`, result.rows);
                    socket.emit(`${base_url}create_response`, result.rows);

                } catch (error) {
                    console.error("Error creating chat message:", error.message);
                    socket.emit(`${base_url}create_error`, { message: error.message });
                }
            });

            socket.on(`${base_url}message_created`, (data) => {
                console.log("MESSAGE CREATED");
                // Perform additional actions or logging here
            });

        });


    }
}

// Export a singleton instance
let socket_instance;

module.exports = {
    user_socket_map,
    getSocketInstance: (server) => {
        if (!socket_instance) {
            socket_instance = new SocketManager(server);
        }
        return socket_instance.io;
    },
};
```

this is the code in the controller that adds the users to the chat

```
const {getSocketInstance,user_socket_map } = require('../../socket/socket_handler')


const joinUserToChat = async (user_id, chat_id) => {
  let io = getSocketInstance()
  try {
      // Retrieve the socket corresponding to the user ID
      // console.log("user_socket_map:  ",user_socket_map)
      const socket_id = user_socket_map.get(user_id);
      io.sockets.sockets.get(socket_id).join(chat_id);

      
     
  } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error joining user to chat:", error.message);
  }
}
```

this is the swiftui socket manager

```
import SwiftUI
import SocketIO



class WebSocketManager {
    static let shared = WebSocketManager()
    
    private var manager: SocketManager
    
    private init() {
        manager = SocketManager(
            socketURL: URL(string:  PlistReaderUtil.getInfoPlistValue(forKey: "server_url")!  )!,
            config: [.log(false), .compress]
        )
    }
    
    func connect() -> Websocket {
        let socket = manager.defaultSocket
        return Websocket(socket: socket)
    }
}

class Websocket: ObservableObject {
    @Published private var socket: SocketIOClient
    @Published var messages = [ChatMessage]()
    
    private var base_url = "chat_message-"
    private var server_url: String =  PlistReaderUtil.getInfoPlistValue(forKey: "server_url")!
    
    private var token_app_storage_util = TokenAppStorageUtil()
    private var is_chat_edit_view_visible_storage_util = IsChatEditViewVisibleAppStorageUtil()
    
    
    init(socket: SocketIOClient) {
        self.socket = socket
    }
    func disconnect() {
        manager.defaultSocket.emit("disconnect", ["token": self.token_app_storage_util.get_access_token()])
        manager.defaultSocket.disconnect()
    }
    
    func connect() {
        setupSocket()
    }
    
    func reconnect() {
        manager.defaultSocket.disconnect()
        setupSocket()
    }
    
    
    
    func get_chat_messages(chat_id: String, completion: @escaping ([ChatMessage]) -> Void) {
        let socket = manager.defaultSocket
        
        var query_params: [String: String] = [
            "chat_id": "=$\(chat_id)",
        ]
        
        socket.on("\(self.base_url)get") { data, ack in
            //                        print("DATA ON get",data)
            if let dictionaries = data[0] as? [[String: Any]] {
                let messages = dictionaries.map { dictionary in
                    var msg = ChatMessage(
                        
                        id: dictionary["id"] as? String ?? "",
                        active: (dictionary["active"] as? Bool)!,
                        created_by: dictionary["created_by"] as? String ?? "",
                        updated_by: dictionary["updated_by"] as? String ?? "",
                        created_on: dictionary["created_on"] as? String ?? "",
                        updated_on: dictionary["updated_on"] as? String ?? "",
                        message: dictionary["message"] as? String ?? "",
                        chat_id: dictionary["chat_id"] as? String ?? ""
                        
                    )
                    return msg
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.messages.append(contentsOf: messages)
                }
            }
        }
        
        socket.emit("\(self.base_url)get", query_params)
    }
    
    func create_chat_message(message: String, chat_id: String) {
        print("[ChatService]   create_chat_message()   \n\n")
        let socket = manager.defaultSocket
        
        var query_params: [String: String] = [
            "chat_id": "\(chat_id)",
            "message": "\(message)"
        ]
        
        socket.emit("\(self.base_url)create", query_params)
    }
    
    
    func setupSocket() {
        let socket = manager.defaultSocket
        
        socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) { [weak self] (data, ack) in
            // Send JWT token after connection is established
            if let token = self!.token_app_storage_util.get_access_token() {
                let data = ["token": token]
                socket.emit("authenticate", token)
            }
            
        }
        
        socket.on("\(self.base_url)chat_create") { [self] (data, ack) in
            
            print("CHAT HAS BEEN CREATED")
            print("data   ",data)
        }
        
        
        socket.on("\(self.base_url)message_created") { [self] (data, ack) in
            print("MESSAGE WAS CREATED")
            if let dictionaries = data[0] as? [[String: Any]] {
                
                let messages = dictionaries.map { dictionary in
                    let msg =  ChatMessage(
                        id: dictionary["id"] as? String ?? "",
                        active: (dictionary["active"] as? Bool)!,
                        created_by: dictionary["created_by"] as? String ?? "",
                        updated_by: dictionary["updated_by"] as? String ?? "",
                        created_on: dictionary["created_on"] as? String ?? "",
                        updated_on: dictionary["updated_on"] as? String ?? "",
                        message: dictionary["message"] as? String ?? "",
                        chat_id: dictionary["chat_id"] as? String ?? ""
                    )
                    if is_chat_edit_view_visible_storage_util.get_is_chat_edit_view_visible() {
                        print("Message receieved INSIDE ",msg.message)
                        
                    }else{
                        print("Message receieved OUTSIDE ",msg.message)
                        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                        content.title = "New msg"
                        content.body = msg.message
                        let request = UNNotificationRequest(
                            identifier:msg.id,
                            content: content,
                            trigger: nil
                        )
                        center.add(request){ error in
                            if let error = error {
                                print(error)
                            }
                        }
                        
                        
                    }
                    return msg
                    
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.messages.append(contentsOf: messages)
                }
            }
        }
        
        socket.connect()
        let access_token = token_app_storage_util.get_access_token()
        print("access_token: ",access_token)
    }
    
    
    internal lazy var manager: SocketManager = {
        SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: server_url)!, config: [.log(false), .compress])
    }()
}
```

when the application first opens i run the setupSocket() command to connect to current chats:::

```
import SwiftUI

struct MiddleWareView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var websocket: Websocket
    @State private var is_loading = true
    private var event_search_settings_util = EventSearchSettingsUtil()
    private var user_util = UserUtil()
    private var bottom_navigatior_height_app_storage_util = BottomNavigatorHeightAppStorageUti()
    private var user_app_storage_util = UserAppStorageUtil()

    var body: some View {
        if is_loading {
            Text("Loading")
                .onAppear(){
                    set_variables()
                }
        }else{

            BottomNavBarView()
            
        }
        
        
        
    }
    
    func set_variables(){
        websocket.setupSocket()
        is_loading = false
        

    }
    
    
}
```

this is the chat edit view::

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct ChatEditView: View {
    @State private var message: String = ""
    @State private var current_int: Int = 0
    
    var chat_id: String
    var event_id: String
    
    
    @State private var is_loading: Bool = true
    @EnvironmentObject var websocket: Websocket
    
    @Namespace var topID
    @Namespace var bottomID
    
    private var is_chat_edit_view_visible_storage_util = IsChatEditViewVisibleAppStorageUtil()
    private let user_app_storage_util = UserAppStorageUtil()
    
    init(chat_id: String,event_id:String ) {
        self.chat_id = chat_id
        self.event_id = event_id
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            VStack{
                if is_loading {
                    Text("... loading")
                }else{
                    ChatMessages(chatService: websocket, proxy: proxy)
                    ChatMessagesInputField(
                        message: $message, create_message_and_scroll_down: {
                            handle_create_chat_message(proxy: proxy)
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
            
            .onAppear(){
                is_chat_edit_view_visible_storage_util.set_is_chat_edit_view_visible(true)
                handle_get_chat_messages()
            }
            .onDisappear(){
                is_chat_edit_view_visible_storage_util.set_is_chat_edit_view_visible(false)
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    func handle_create_chat_message(proxy:ScrollViewProxy) {
        if message == "" {return}
        websocket.create_chat_message(message: message, chat_id: chat_id)
        self.message = ""
        withAnimation {
            proxy.scrollTo(websocket.messages.count - 1, anchor: .bottom)
        }
    }
    
    
    
    func calculate_is_current_user(message_created_by: String) -> Bool {
        let user = user_app_storage_util.get_user()!
        return String(user.id) == String(message_created_by)
    }
    
    func handle_get_chat_messages() {
        
        if websocket.manager.status == .connected {
            print("ALREADY CONNECTED!")
            websocket.get_chat_messages(chat_id: chat_id) { messages in
                
            }
        } else {
            websocket.manager.defaultSocket.on("connect") { _, _ in
                print("NEED TO CONNECT")
                websocket.get_chat_messages(chat_id: chat_id) { messages in
                }
            }
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.3) {
            withAnimation {
                is_loading = false
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```